# long errors in opencv

Tags: c++, linux, opencv

I have a C++ program with opencv as follows :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include</usr/local/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
int main()
{
Mat image=imread("/home/c++/edge detection/DisplayImage.JPG",1);
//imshow("DisplayImage",image);
return 0;
}
```

My CMakeLists.txt is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(openCVTest)
# cmake needs this line
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)

# Define project name
project(opencv)

# Find OpenCV, you may need to set OpenCV_DIR variable
# to the absolute path to the directory containing OpenCVConfig.cmake file
# via the command line or GUI
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

# If the package has been found, several variables will
# be set, you can find the full list with descriptions
# in the OpenCVConfig.cmake file.
# Print some message showing some of them
message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS "2.8.11")
    # Add OpenCV headers location to your include paths
    include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
endif()

# Declare the executable target built from your sources
add_executable(opencv opencv.cpp)

# Link your application with OpenCV libraries
target_link_libraries(opencv ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

When I run my program in my Ubuntu 16 Terminal, I get [too many errors](https://github.com/Sanmitha-Sadhishkumar/Error.txt/blob/main/error_file). This error is too long hence I uploaded in git.

I don't know why these much errors come and I don't know the reason for it. I am a newbie to opencv hence please please be easy to me.

Advance thanks for any help :)

EDIT : updated the file in git.

I installed libopencv-dev

```
sudo apt install libopencv-dev
```

And my pkg-config opencv --libs output is :

```
$pkg-config opencv --libs
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_calib3d.so -lopencv_calib3d /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_contrib.so -lopencv_contrib /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_core.so -lopencv_core /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_features2d.so -lopencv_features2d /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_flann.so -lopencv_flann /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_gpu.so -lopencv_gpu /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_highgui.so -lopencv_highgui /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_imgproc.so -lopencv_imgproc /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_legacy.so -lopencv_legacy /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_ml.so -lopencv_ml /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_objdetect.so -lopencv_objdetect /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_ocl.so -lopencv_ocl /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_photo.so -lopencv_photo /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_stitching.so -lopencv_stitching /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_superres.so -lopencv_superres /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_ts.so -lopencv_ts /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_video.so -lopencv_video /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libopencv_videostab.so -lopencv_videostab
```

Why do I get these many errors when I run such a simple program? Kindly anyone help me

Comment: Start with solving the first one: 'error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"' by figuring out how to enable C++11 support.

Comment: First try to specify your target language: `project(DisplayImage LANGUAGES CXX)`.

Comment: Are sure you are using a C++11 or later compiler? 

/usr/include/opencv2/core/cvdef.h:740:4: error: #error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"

Comment: Tip: when there's more than one error, concentrate on the one that occurs first and ignore everything that follows.

Comment: your compiler is too old. find out the version of your compiler.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, please check that git link now. Please check my edits

Comment: ubuntu 16? yeah, no, that won't do.

Comment: Then any alteratives? @ChristophRackwitz

Answer (score 0):

the error you posted:

> error "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"

that means you need to build the code and "tell the compiler" to use c++11

you can set the flag in cmake doing:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
```

this flag is only available since 3.1

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html

Comment: I made these changes. And gave `cmake .` still the error appears. Pls check my edit